# VHDL - how does "reset" work and how to use?

Tags: vhdl, reset, fpga, xilinx

I am new to VHDL and am trying to understand how `reset` operates  - specifically within the Xilinx Spartan6.  I've looked over this site and others, a white paper or two, but my questions do not seem to be addressed (so I fear the issue is so basic that all is assumed!)

Anyway, I inherited some example code and have made significant changes to it and succeeded in getting some decent functionality but the use of reset mystifies me.

The code looks like this:

```
architecture Behavioral of BigProject is
...
    signal reset : std_logic := 0;
...
begin
...
    reset <= '0';
...

    process(clk_1MHz, reset) is
    begin
        if reset = '1' then
            foo_flag <= '0';
            fsm_a <= FSM_FIRST_STATE;
        elsif rising_edge(clk_1MHz) then
            case fsm_a is
                when FSM_FIRST_STATE =>
                    <do stuff>
                when FSM_SECOND_STATE =>
                    <do other stuff>
                when others =>
                    null;
            end case;
        end if;
    end process;
```

What does my use of `reset` actually accomplish?

Thanks.

Comment: This isn't really a VHDL question but a (yes, basic) digital hardware question ... a good logic design textbook would be useful here. Normally, you arrange for "Reset" to go active after applying power - then, when you de-assert it, the circuit is in a known starting state (e.g. with a clock blinking 00:00)

Comment: I understand what a reset is...of course. My issue is with the construct in my example code (never said it was good or valid!) AND with how does one implement an actual reset - that is, without an input port  Thanks.

Comment: Usually, WITH an input port. However, Xilinx also used to have a "global reset" component you could instantiate in your top level design, it would drive a "Reset" signal at the appropriate moment. ISE also allows you to initialise signals in the declaration, thus the design comes up in this state after configuration, but you can't reset it later (except by reconfiguration). Search Xilinx website for XAPP appnotes on reset, there's at least one with the details.

Comment: I take it you mean 
http://www.xilinx.com/support/documentation/white_papers/wp272.pdf
My dev board appears to NOT have any kind of "hardware" reset that I can use to drive an FPGA input port (which, again, is troubling)

Comment: If your dev board has a FPGA input pin that connects to a push button, then it has hardware you can use if you wish. Typically you'd arrange something (like a "power good" monitor") to do the job when you move to prototype hardware if you need a reset. Some applications I work on require an external reset driven by a watchdog timer, for example, to restart the hardware if a radiation-induced glitch stops it.

Answer (score 1):

With respect to the Xilinx tools, initial values on signals are honored for power-on state.  For example:

```
signal a : std_logic := '0';
signal b : std_logic := '1';
```

Signal `a` will have a power-on reset value of '0', and signal `b` will have a power-on reset value of '1'.

Now, this is generally NOT the case for ASIC's, and is not the case for Microsemi parts.

Also, it is highly recommended that you limit the resets to only those bits that actually need to be reset.  For example, if you have a data path that does math operations on some data in a pipeline, do you need to reset the data itself?  Resets have a cost in terms of logic (depending on the logic library, it may require a multiplexer), routing (the reset has to get everywhere it is necessary), and can be complex when releasing reset.

So, limit your resets as much as possible.  If an external reset is not necessary, don't use one.  And if it is required, limit it's use to essential bits.

Answer (score 0):

Your reset actually accomplishes nothing ;) In your code the reset is tied to '0' and thus your clocked process is always in reset state.

Usually the reset signal is an input port. So someone outside of your module asserts the reset for clock cycle or more and then releases it. After that all your registers are (or should be) in knowns states and your design is ready to do what ever it does.

edit: sorry, the reset is active high, so the tie-0 in for your reset actually makes sure that the clocked process is *not* reset. Ever. So every time your design starts from unknown state. That would be the red x's you see in the simulation waveform.

Comment: Re: your edit.   Hmm. OK. That was my concern ;)  So, how do I implement the equivalent of a power-on reset? or do I simply initialize everything?

Comment: Using Test Bench I see that I enter FSM_FIRST_STATE (nearly) immediately. So how am I getting there?  I mean, I'm happy I do - so my design works -  but can't explain why.

Comment: Sorry for the late comment. Basically you drive the reset pin from your test bench which is outside of your *BigProject* entity. Activate reset, wait for few clocks and release it.

Answer (score 0):

`signal reset : std_logic := ***'0'***;`

> In your code the reset is tied to '0' and thus your clocked process is always in reset state.

@Jarno: That's not correct. For a synthesized module for Altera this doesn't matter ... even if there would be a `1` for the reset.
If you synthesize the code you will see that the synthesizer ignores that value. Maybe you even get a warning that the init value is ignored.

[http://quartushelp.altera.com/14.0/mergedProjects/msgs/msgs/wvrfx2_vhdl_warning_initial_value_for_signal_is_ignored.htm][1]

PS: Sorry, I am not allowed to write comments, yet.

Comment: Note the 'reset <= '0';' line in the code. So the reset is forced active in there too. On the otherhand, I always though that FPGAs allow default values in the signal declaration? Since the values are loadad from the image every time you boot anyway. Bad habit? Maybe ;)

Comment: Then you are right, I missed that second line. .... Except for the testbench, I don't use such init values. As you see (Altera & Xilinx) synthesizers react differently to init values.